# Global Replace with js

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```
[27564][85938][457438][273][48232]
```

I want to replace all the [ with ''.  I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
 var str = '[27564][85938][457438][273][48232]'
 var nChar = '[';
 var re = new RegExp(nChar, 'g')    
 var visList = str.replace(re,'');
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `RegExp` instead of `/.../g`? Could the value of nChar change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the `[` otherwise it is interpreted as the start of a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
var nChar = '\\[';
```

If nChar is a variable (and I assume it is otherwise there would be little point in using `RegExp` instead of `/.../g`) then you may find this question useful:

- [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "[27564][85938][457438][273][48232]";
alert(string.replace(/\[/g, '')); //outputs 27564]85938]457438]273]48232]
```

I escaped the `[` character and used a global flag to replace all instances of the character.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem today. 
The requirement is replace all "c++" in user input string. Because "+" has meaning in Reg expression, string.replace fails. 
So I wrote a multi-replace function for js string. Hope this can help.

```
String.prototype.mreplace = function (o, n) {
    var off = 0;
    var start = 0;
    var ret = "";
    while(true){
        off = this.indexOf(o, start);
        if (off < 0)
        {
            ret += this.substring(start, this.length);
            break;
        }
        ret += this.substring(start, off) + n;
        start = off + o.length;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Example:
    "ababc".mreplace("a", "a--");  // returns "a--ba--bc"